# Returning objects from GetSomethingAsync callbacks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, task, async-await

I am using the [DropNet](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet) API for connecting to DropBox. I am struggling around async/await concepts though.

I have a method is calling the api `GetTokenAsync`. The return type is `void`, and there is a success and failure action to callback.

```
public async Task<GetTokenResult> GetAuthorizationUrl()
{
    var result = new GetTokenResult();

    _dropNetClient.GetTokenAsync(
        login =>
            {
                result.Url = _dropNetClient.BuildAuthorizeUrl(_authorizationCallback.ToString());
                result.Success = true;
            },
        exception =>
            {
                result.Error = exception.ToDiagnosticString();
                result.Success = false;
            }
        );

    return result;
}
```

The problem? I am thinking that changing the return type to just `GetTokenResult` *may* return faster than the actions will, therefore my results will never get set. I cannot `await` the async method as it returns void.

This is the one concept around async/await that I cannot wrap my head around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using a [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx):

```
public Task<GetTokenResult> GetAuthorizationUrl()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<GetTokenResult>();   
    _dropNetClient.GetTokenAsync(
        login => tcs.SetResult(new GetTokenResult { 
            Url = _dropNetClient.BuildAuthorizeUrl(
                      _authorizationCallback.ToString()),
            Success = true
        },
        exception => tcs.SetResult(new GetTokenResult { 
            Error = exception.ToDiagnosticString(),
            Success = true
        });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The returned task will only complete when the `GetTokenAsync` operation completes (via one of the callbacks), and you can await it from an async method.

I would personally use `SetException` instead of `SetResult` on failure though - so that if you await the returned task, it will throw the appropriate failure on an exception, rather than just setting the value differently. It's more idiomatically .NET-like.

EDIT: You could then change the code to return `Task<string>` instead:

```
public Task<string> GetAuthorizationUrl()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();   
    _dropNetClient.GetTokenAsync(
        login => tcs.SetResult(_dropNetClient.BuildAuthorizeUrl
                                    _authorizationCallback.ToString()),
        exception => tcs.SetException(exception));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now the exception would be propagated within the task itself - if you `await` a task which faults, the exception is thrown at that point. No need for extra properties, etc - it's much closer to how you'd write the corresponding synchronous code.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Can you give me an example in the usage of this method & the SetException? I'm failing to understand and see where you'd be consuming the exception. In the caller of this method I would assume you want to await GetAuthorizationUrl(), which removes the GetTokenResult and no longer the task.

Comment: @TimGabrhel: What do you mean by "removes the GetTokenResult and no longer the task"? Yes, you'd await `GetAuthorizationUrl` - but if you use `tcs.SetException(exception)` instead of making your GetTokenResult have Error/Success properties, it means you can just catch the exception if you want to, or let it propagate otherwise. Heck, you could even change to just use `Task<string>` as the only *success* information you're returning is a string.

Comment: I'm hung up on the usage of the exception. Are you saying that you have to consume the exception here within this method? In my case, I'd like to propogate the exception back to the UI (WindowsPhone) so I can allow the user to email an error report which contain the exception details. Because I want to propogate, I'm missing the concept of how I'd return the exception details if the actual return type to the caller is GetTokenResult because of the await keyword.

Comment: @TimGabrhel: No, the point is that the callback would set the exception in the `TaskCompletionSource`, and then when you await the task, then exception would be thrown at that point. That's more idiomatic than setting it in a property. I wasn't suggesting making the return type `GetTokenResult` - look at the method I've given you... it's `Task<GetTokenResult>`. When you await that, you'll get a `GetTokenResult`. But I'm saying that you could change it to `Task<string>`, just propagate the URL in the success case and set an exception in the failure case. Will update answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing this point: _if you await a task which faults, the exception is thrown at that point._.